# How to Launch a compute Instance with data disk in IBM cloud using softlayer Rest API

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to launch compute instance with volume creation using softlayer rest API and need to launch using globalIdentifier.

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest.json

Body:
{
    "parameters": [{
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest",
        "maxMemory": 4,
        "hostname": "jagatest",
        "maxCpu": 2,
        "domain": "test.local",
        "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
        "startCpus": 1,
        "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
            "globalIdentifier": "375c7ad3-1b39-4c58-a657-7fc4351d7b06"
        },
        "blockDevices": [{
                "device": "0",
                "diskImage": {
                    "capacity": 25
                }
            },
            {
                "device": "2",
                "diskImage": {
                    "capacity": 10
                }
            }
        ],
        "localDiskFlag": false,
        "datacenter": {
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Location",
            "name": "sjc01"
        }
    }]
}

Error Through:

{"error":"Invalid value provided for 'blockDevices'. Block devices may not be provided when using an image template.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following next request

Method POST

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject.json

Body

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest",
      "maxMemory": 4,
      "hostname": "jagatest",
      "maxCpu": 2,
      "domain": "test.local",
      "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
      "startCpus": 1,
      "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
        "globalIdentifier": "375c7ad3-1b39-4c58-a657-7fc4351d7b06"
      },
      "localDiskFlag": false,
      "datacenter": {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Location",
        "name": "sjc01"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Daniel. I need to add two data disk with globalIdentifier.

Comment: as a workaround first provision a VSI, then you update with all disks you need in the VSI.